# NSIS to install ruby gems

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, installation, nsis

this is a function I have in nsis script:

```
Function rubyDependencies
    DetailPrint "Installing Web Runtime Environment dependencies..."
    ExecWait "gem install rails –v2.3.8"
    ExecWait "gem install rake –v0.8.7"
    ExecWait "gem uninstall rake –v10.0.3"
    ExecWait "rake gems:install"
    DetailPrint "Dependencies installed."
FunctionEnd
```

I have tried:

```
ExecWait '"gem install rails -v2.3.8" $0'
```

And nothing was displaying on $0, but gem list remained empty.

Any help?

Thanks,
  Telmo Cardoso

EDIT:
I'm still having problems. I'm now using:

```
nsExec::ExecToLog '"$INSTDIR\runtime\ruby\bin\gem.bat" install --ignore-dependencies --no-rdoc --no-ri rails -v=2.3.8'
```

And its generating:

```
could not find a valid gem '-v=2.3.8'
```

and install latest one. So clearly something weird its being passed in the parameter. When I run the command outside installer, it works as supposed.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `ExecWait '"c:\full\path\to\program.exe" param1 "space param" param3' $0`. For `ExecWait '"gem" ...'` to work, gem.exe needs to be in a path searched by [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)...